# Python - FastApi Local Server Deployment

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a Python FAST Api running locally on my Windows Machine (Uvicorn) and endpoints work fine via Local Host.
I'm new to this and wanted to know if I can have the Webserver run on a local Windows or Virtual machine on Corporate LAN and have other users access the endpoint.

If Yes, may I know how to and Can some link to an article.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Local Host works fine

Comment: Well depending on your companies firewall settings, it might be easy or difficult. Generally speaking if certain port works on your local machine, you can ask uvicorn to listen to interface `0.0.0.0` or internal IP of your pc (find it with `ipconfig` under windows, example `192.168.0.150`) and give them address `http://192.168.0.150:<port>/docs`

Comment: @BijayRegmi - Thank you . Let me give it a try